# how to pass values from view-controller-model and fetch the result codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**MY CONTROLLER PAGE**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Searchresult extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct(){
 parent::__construct();
 $this->load->model('searchresultss','','TRUE');
    }
 public function users()
 {
     $this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->view('includes/kheader');
$data['showdata']   =   $this->searchresultss->login();
$this->load->view('searchresult',$data);

$this->load->view('includes/khelp');
$this->load->view('includes/kfooter');
 }
}
```

**MY MODEL PAGE**

```
<?php
Class Searchresultss extends CI_Model
{

 function login($per_page=3)
 {


$query="SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE  

if('$se_ct'!='',sect =  '$se_ct' AND if('$subsect' !='',subsect =  '$subsect',subsect like  '%%'),sect like  '%%' AND subsect like  '%%')
AND
IF( '$cou_ntry' !='', country =  '$cou_ntry'
AND 
if('$sta_te' !='', state =  '$sta_te'
AND  
if('$ci_ty' !='',city =  '$ci_ty',city like  '%%'),state LIKE  '%%'
AND city LIKE  '%%'), country LIKE  '%%'
AND state LIKE  '%%'
AND city LIKE  '%%' ) 
AND age >=  '$age_from'
AND age <=  '$age_to'
AND 
IF('$qualification' !='',qualification =  '$qualification',  qualification LIKE  '%%' ) 
AND gender =  '$look'
And status='1'";
$data=array();
$query=$this->db->query($query);
$data['results']=$query->result();
$data['count']=$query->num_rows();
$data['pages']=ceil($count/$per_page);

return $data;
 }
}
```

**THIS  IS MY HTML PAGE**

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>searchresult/users" method="post">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab_content" >

        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Looking for</td>
    <td>
    <input type="radio" name="look" id="look" value="female" checked="checked"/> <span style="color:#000000;">Bride</span> <input type="radio" name="look" id="look" value="male" /><span style="color:#000000;"> Groom</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td> <span style="color:#000000;">From </span>
         <select name="age_from" id="age" class="inp_age"   >
    <option>18</option>
    <option>19</option>
<option selected>20</option>
<option>21</option>
<option>22</option>
 </select><span style="color:#000000;">&nbsp; To</span>
                     <select name="age_to" id="age" class="inp_age"   >
       <option>18</option>
    <option>19</option>
<option >20</option>

<option>23</option>
<option>24</option>
<option>25</option>
<option>26</option>

<option selected="selected">70</option>
          </select>
         </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sect</td>
    <td><select name="sect" id="sect" onchange="return SelectSect(this.value);" class="inp_search" >
  <!-- <select name="cont" id="cont" onchange="return SelectState(this.value);" class="inp">-->
          <option value="">Any sect</option>
            <?php
         $sect=mysql_query("select sect_id,sect_name from `geo_sect` order by sect_name asc");
         while($sects=mysql_fetch_array($sect))
         {
         ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $sects['sect_id'];?>"><?php echo $sects['sect_name'];?></option>
         <?php
         }
         ?>

           </select></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Sub Sect</td>
    <td><select name="subsect" id="subsect"  onchange="return SelectSub(this.value);" class="inp_search" >
<!--<select name="state" id="state"  onchange="return SelectCity(this.value);" class="inp" >-->
         <option value="">Any subsect</option>

           </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Country</td>
    <td> <select name="country" id="country" onchange="return SelectState(this.value);" class="inp_search">
         <option value="">Any Country</option>
         <?php
         $countries=mysql_query("select country_id,Country_name from `kk.geo_countries` order by Country_name asc");
         while($country=mysql_fetch_array($countries))
         {
         ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id'];?>" style="width:10px"><?php echo $country['Country_name'];?></option>
          <?php
          }
          ?>
           </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>State</td>
    <td><select name="state" id="state"  onchange="return SelectCity(this.value);" class="inp_search" >
         <option value="">Any state</option>

           </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>City</td>
    <td> <select name="city" id="city" class="inp_search" >
         <option value="">Any city</option>

          </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Qualification</td>
    <td><select name="qualification" id="qualification"  class="inp_search" >
     <option value="">Any  qualification</option>
        <?php
         $qualification=mysql_query("select qualification_id,qualification from `qualification` order by qualification asc");
         while($qualifications=mysql_fetch_array($qualification))
         {
         ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $qualifications['qualification_id'];?>"><?php echo $qualifications['qualification'];?></option>
          <?php
          }
          ?>
 </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>  <div style="padding-left:100px;"> <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button green search_btn" value="Search" /></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
 </form>
```

WHEN I USE

```
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($showdata);
```

IN MY VIEW PAGE IAM GETTING an error

```
 A PHP Error was encountered
 Severity: Notice
 Message: Undefined variable: se_ct ........
```

Is this the correct way to pass values from view to controller to model? I am not sure that my controller is passing values to model and also I am not sure about the model page.

Comment: You're "not sure"? Could you show us what output you're getting and what you're expecting to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am talking about the error according to your question, so below is my opinion.

i think the problem in the below line

```
$data['results']=$query->result();
```

it should be like

```
$data['results']=$query->result_array();
```

then do the following

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($showdata);
```

it will not show any error.The process is not right.You should take all values in the controllers like as @Aeolun said then pass it in the function.

and also your model function should look like

```
model function login($look,$age,$se_ct,$subsect,$coun_try, $sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification)
```

remove $per_page=3 from the function as you defined it as 3.so no need to pass it as a parameter.

Please let me know if you need anything.

**/* Update */**

controller function

```
$look = $this->input->post('gender');
$age_from = $this->input->post('age_from');
$age_to = $this->input->post('age_to');
$age = $this->input->post('age');
$se_ct = $this->input->post('sect');
$subsect = $this->input->post('subsect');
$coun_try = $this->input->post('country');
$sta_te = $this->input->post('state');
$ci_ty = $this->input->post('city');
$qualification = $this->input->post('qualification');

$data['showdata']   =   $this->searchresultss->login($per_page=3,$look,$age, $age_to,$age_from,$se_ct,$subsect,$cou‌​n_try, $sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification);
```

and model function

```
model function login($per_page,$look,$age,$age_to,$age_from,$se_ct,$subsect,$coun_try, $sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification)
```

and your query should look like

```
$query="SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE  

if('$se_ct'!='',sect =  '$se_ct' AND if('$subsect' !='',subsect =  '$subsect',subsect like  '%%'),sect like  '%%' AND subsect like  '%%')
AND
IF( '$coun_try' !='', country =  '$coun_try'
AND 
if('$sta_te' !='', state =  '$sta_te'
AND  
if('$ci_ty' !='',city =  '$ci_ty',city like  '%%'),state LIKE  '%%'
AND city LIKE  '%%'), country LIKE  '%%'
AND state LIKE  '%%'
AND city LIKE  '%%' ) 
AND age >=  '$age_from'
AND age <=  '$age_to'
AND 
IF('$qualification' !='',qualification =  '$qualification',  qualification LIKE  '%%' ) 
AND gender =  '$look'
And status='1'";
$data=array();
$query=$this->db->query($query);
$data['results']=$query->result_array();
$data['count']=$query->num_rows();
$data['pages']=ceil($data['count']/3); // if $per_page is undefined the make it 3;
```

Comment: its my pleasure.if you have any confusions you can ask me.

Comment: just write echo $query;die; after the query and then run the page and put the query into the database and see what error it tells.

Comment: dude it worked ...thanks .Now thing is that how to print individual value in view page

Comment: hi Aborty how are you

Answer (score 0):

Your method for passing values between the controller, view and model is correct as far as I can see, except you are missing all input parameters except for 'per_page', which you should all add to the model function.

```
//IN MODEL
function login($sect, $country, $state, $city, $per_page=3)
```

Then, when you have added those parameters to the model function, you can get them from the request by using:

```
//IN CONTROLLER
$sect = $this->input->post('sect');
$country = $this->input->post('country');
$state = $this->input->post('state');
$city = $this->input->post('city');
$this->searchresultss->login($sect, $country, $state, $city);
```

You also have a potential SQL Injection vulnerability in the query in your model, use the parameters facility built into Codeigniter. Eg:

```
//IN MODEL
$query="select * from users where country = ? AND sect = ? AND state = ? AND city = ? limit ?";
$query=$this->db->query($query, [ $country, $sect, $state, $city, $per_page ]);
```

In addition, you are using additional SQL queries directly in your view, which you would probably want to move to the model you already have, or a different model.

PLEASE NOTE: I have not used all the fields you have in your form, as I think that would make the example unclear, but you can just use the same method to add the rest of the fields.

Comment: That was in brief, what specifically do you want to know?